# submit button not sending form data

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on `SUBMIT` it's doing nothing. But I need to send form data to an external link. How can I do this?

```
   <form role="form" class="registration-form" action="javascript:void(0);">
      <fieldset id="1ststep" class="show">...

       .........Different input fields go here.......

      <div class="text-center btn-box">
         <button type="submit" class="btn Dbtn9" 
            id="btn10thstep">SUBMIT</button>
      </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: post your javascript code

Comment: you need a name in order to send data from your form inputs

Comment: On submit the `action` is executed which in your case is `javascript:void(0);` - you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Actually, I don't know what is the use of javascript:void(0) in action value and then I replaced it (javascript:void(0)) by the external link but when I click on submit button, it does nothing.

Comment: I think I need to add <script>...make a function that redirect to external link when i clicked on submit...</script>  and need to add method="post"

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve]. Include an input. Tell us how you are determining it isn't being sent. You said you replaced `action="javascript:void(0);"` with the URL you wanted to submit the data to: Show us that. Why do you think you need to use JavaScript? Forms are designed to submit data with just HTML. Why do you think you need to add method="POST"?

Comment: Ok, "https://healthy.exchange/form.php"  is the url of form, and I need to send the data to "http://www.quotit.net/eproIFP/webPages/logQuote/logQuote.asp", For submit data, we need license number, that I have so that is not problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the inputs needs to have name=""

Answer (score 1):

After your comment that you do not know about the `action="javascript:void(0);"` part in your code, here an answer:

If you just need to submit a form, just add the URL as `action` and the correct method as required by the server. Unless you need to run business logic between the user action and the actual submit to the server, the default browser behavior (without js) works just fine?

Example:

```
<form role="form" class="registration-form" method="POST" action="/register">
```

`action` can be either relative, absolute or a complete URL including protocol and host. However, any GET parameters will be discarded (no matter which method is used to submit). If you need to submit any additional parameters, you have to add them as `hidden` inputs to the form (or you add them in the AJAX call, if you choose the JS solution).

If you need to run business logic in between the user's submit action and the actual POST or GET to the server, you can either leave the `action` as is or replace it with `#`.

```
<form id="registation-form" role="form" class="registration-form" method="POST" action="#">
```

in javascript:

```
let registrationForm = document.getElementById('registration-form');
registrationForm.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //... your business logic here
    // submit the form, e.g. using jQuery's ajax() function
});
```

jQuery.ajax(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/